# My D3 chart's legend and axis/tick labels appear in Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js, svg

I made a bar chart in D3. The bars and gridlines are visible in Chrome, but not the labels. Everything is visible in Firefox. [Here's the CSV file I'm using](https://github.com/chrismp/Population-growth-2010-2014/blob/master/dataset.csv). Here's my code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .axis {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .x line,
    .y .domain {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x line {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .x .domain {
        display: none;
    }

    .legend text,
    .axis text {
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: #000;
    }

    .city text {
        font: 16px sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<h3>How population changed in American cities with 500,000+ people, 2010-2014</h3>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Add commas to numbers. Example: 1000 becomes 1,000.
    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    function apCityNameStyling(cityStateString){
        // This isn't exact AP styling, but pretty close
        var apCities = {
            'Atlanta, Georgia': 'Atlanta',
            'Baltimore, Maryland': 'Baltimore',
            'Boston, Massachusetts': 'Boston',
            'Chicago, Illinois': 'Chicago',
            'Cincinnati, Ohio': 'Cincinnati',
            'Cleveland, Ohio': 'Cleveland',
            'Dallas, Texas': 'Dallas',
            'Denver, Colorado': 'Denver',
            'Detroit, Michigan': 'Detroit',
            'Honolulu, Hawaii': 'Honolulu',
            'Houston, Texas': 'Houston',
            'Indianapolis  (balance), Indiana': 'Indianapolis',
            'Las Vegas, Nevada': 'Las Vegas',
            'Los Angeles, California': 'Los Angeles',
            'Miami, Florida': 'Miami',
            'Milwaukee, Wisconsin': 'Milwaukee',
            'Minneapolis, Minnesota': 'Minneapolis',
            'Nashville-Davidson (balance), Tennessee': 'Nashville, Tennessee', // Not a standalone city, but the key here is how the Census calls Nashville, TN
            'New Orleans, Louisiana': 'New Orleans',
            'New York, New York': 'New York City',
            'Oklahoma City, Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
            'Philadelphia, Pennsylvania': 'Philadelphia',
            'Phoenix, Arizona': 'Phoenix',
            'Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania': 'Pittsburgh',
            'Salt Lake City, Utah': 'Salt Lake City',
            'San Antonio, Texas': 'San Antonio',
            'San Diego, California': 'San Diego',
            'San Francisco, California': 'San Francisco',
            'Seattle, Washington': 'Seattle',
            'St. Louis, Missouri': 'St. Louis',
            'Washington, District of Columbia': 'Washington, D.C.'
        };

        if(cityStateString in apCities){
            return apCities[cityStateString];
        } else {
            return cityStateString;
        }
    }



    var colorArray = [
        '#9ecae1',
        '#3182bd'
    ];
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(colorArray);

    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 105
    };
    var marginTop = margin.top;
    var marginLeft = margin.left;
    var marginBottom = margin.bottom;
    var marginRight = margin.right;
    var width = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].clientWidth*0.95 - marginLeft - marginRight;
    var widthWithMargins = width+marginRight+marginLeft;
    var height = 2000;
    var chart = d3.select('.chart')
        .attr('width',widthWithMargins);

    d3.csv('public/datasets/US cities population 2010 to 2014.csv', function(error,csvData){
        var data = csvData.filter(function(d){
            return +d.population2014>=500000;
        });

        var maxPopulation2014 = d3.max(
                data,
                function(d){
                    return +d.population2014;
                }
            );
        var dataCount = data.length;

        var yearColumnNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key){ 
            return (key!=="Id" && key!=="City");
        });

        data.sort(
            function(a,b){
                return +b.population2014 - +a.population2014; // Sort by 2014 population, highest to lowest
            }
        );

        data.forEach(function(d){
            d.apCityName = apCityNameStyling(d.City);
            d.years = yearColumnNames.map(function(name){
                return {
                    name: name,
                    value: +d[name]
                };
            });
        });

        chart.attr('height',height)
            .attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+','+marginTop+')');

        // X axis stuff
        var xDomainMin = 400000;
        var x = d3.scale.log()
            .domain([xDomainMin,maxPopulation2014])
            .range([0,width]); // Make range smaller than chart width so x axis doesn't go off the edge of chart's SVG canvas

        var xTicks = [
            // xDomainMin,
            500000,
            1000000,
            2000000,
            4000000,
            8000000
        ];
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .tickValues(xTicks)
            .tickFormat(d3.format('s'))
            .innerTickSize(-height)
            .orient('top');

        chart.append('g')
            .attr('class','x axis')
            .call(xAxis)
            .append('text')
                .text('Population')
                .style('text-anchor','end')
                .attr('class','axis-label')
                .attr('x',widthWithMargins/2)
                .attr('y',-25);

        var cityNameArray = data.map(function(d){
            return d.apCityName;
        });
        var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(cityNameArray)
            .rangeRoundBands([0,height-marginTop],0.15);
        var y1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(yearColumnNames)
            .rangeRoundBands([0,y0.rangeBand()]);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y0)
            .orient('left');

        chart.append('g')
            .attr('class','y axis')
            .call(yAxis);

        var city = chart.selectAll('.city')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class','city')
            .attr('transform',function(d){
                return 'translate('+0+','+y0(d.apCityName)+')';
            });

        city.selectAll('rect')
            .data(function(d){
                return d.years;
            })
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
                .attr('height',function(d){
                    return y1.rangeBand();
                })
                .attr('width',function(d){
                    return x(d.value);
                })
                .attr('y',function(d){
                    return y1(d.name);
                })
                .style('fill',function(d){
                    return color(d.name);
                })

        var popThreshold = 1500000; // Proxy for bar width
        city.selectAll('.city')
            .data(function(d){
                return d.years;
            })
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x',function(d){
                var population = d.value;
                var xPop = x(population);
                return population>=popThreshold ? xPop-3 : xPop+3;
            })
            .attr('y',function(d){
                return y1(d.name)+(y1.rangeBand()/1.3);
            })
            .attr('text-anchor',function(d){
                return d.value>=popThreshold ? 'end' : 'start';
            })
            .attr('fill',function(d){
                return d.value>=popThreshold ? '#eee' : '#000';
            })
            .attr('stroke',function(d){
                return d.value<popThreshold ? '#fff' : '';
            })
            .attr('stroke-width',function(d){
                return d.value<popThreshold ? 5 : '';
            })
            .attr('paint-order','stroke')
            .text(function(d){
                return numberWithCommas(d.value);
            });

        var insertLinebreaks = function (d,i) {
            // Get `y` value for `g` element containing each cluster of bars
                var gCityY = d3.selectAll('.city')[0][i]
                .getAttribute('transform')
                .split(',')[1]
                .replace(')','');
            var yTick = d3.selectAll('.y .tick')[0][i];
            var el = d3.select(this);
            var words = d.indexOf(', ') > -1 ? d.split(', ').map(function(w,i){return i===0 ? w+',' : w}) : d.split(' ');

            el.text('');
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
                if(i===0){
                    tspan.attr('dx',5);
                } else if (i > 0){
                    tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '15');
                }
            }

            if(words.length>1){
                var cityNameY = words.length===3 ? +gCityY+10 : +gCityY+20;
                yTick.setAttribute('transform','translate(-2.5,'+cityNameY+')');
            }   
        };

        chart.selectAll('.y .tick text').each(insertLinebreaks);

        var legend = chart.selectAll('.legend')
            .data(yearColumnNames.slice())
            .enter()
            .append('g')
                .attr('class','legend')
                .attr('transform',function(d,i){
                    return 'translate(0,'+(i*20)+')';
                })

        var legendX = width - width - marginLeft;
        legend.append('rect')
            .attr('x',legendX)
            .attr('y',-marginTop)
            .attr('height',18)
            .attr('width',18)
            .style('fill',color);

        legend.append('text')
            .attr('x', legendX + 55)
            .attr('y',-35)
            .style('text-anchor','end')
            .text(function(d){
                return d.replace(/\D/g,'');
            });
    });
</script>
```

Here are [pictures](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2564) of how the chart looks in Firefox vs Chrome.

Why is this compatible with Firefox v41, but not Chrome v45?

Comment: you do not have `main` see->  `document.getElementsByTagName('main')`

Comment: try using
    `var widthWithMargins = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;` 
    `var width = widthWithMargins*0.95 - marginLeft - marginRight;` but this does not fix issue

Comment: `chart.attr('height',height).attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+','+marginTop+')');` I do not think you can use translate on the svg element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

Comment: @CrandellWS I do have `main` in my page. Sorry for not mentioning that. I'm using github pages. You can check the repo at https://github.com/chrismp/chrismp.github.io. I also updated my question to include pics of the chart in Firefox vs Chrome

Comment: did a pull request hope that helps

Comment: @CrandellWS SVG 2 supports setting a transform on an `<svg>` element. SVG 1.1 does not. Firefox has implemented this part of SVG 2, Chrome has not yet done so although it has implemented other parts that Firefox has not. This situation will continue as the unfinished SVG 2 specification evolves and browsers evolve with it.

Comment: @Robert Longson Do you know of a comparison list?

Comment: @CrandellWS there isn't one yet that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the svg element was being set to transform

```
chart.attr('height',height).attr('transform','translate(' + marginLeft + ',' + margin‌​Top + ')');
```

In answer to the Question of why as @Robert Longson stated:

> SVG 2 supports setting a transform on an `<svg>` element. SVG 1.1 does
>   not. Firefox has implemented this part of SVG 2, Chrome has not yet
>   done so although it has implemented other parts that Firefox has not.
>   This situation will continue as the unfinished SVG 2 specification
>   evolves and browsers evolve with it

So the following changes hopefully help:

```
    var legend = chart.selectAll('.legend')
        .data(yearColumnNames.slice())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
            .attr('class','legend')
            .attr('transform',function(d,i){

                return 'translate('+marginLeft+','+(marginTop+(i*20))+')';
            })

    chart.attr('height',height);
        // .attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+','+marginTop+')');
 //added
    chart.selectAll('.y')
        .attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+')');
 //added
    chart.selectAll('.x')
        .attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+','+marginTop+')');
    var city = chart.selectAll('.city')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class','city')
        .attr('transform',function(d){
            return 'translate('+marginLeft+','+(y0(d.apCityName)+(marginTop/2))+')';
```

The snippet will not show the display results (so only code) because it can not pull the remote data... So a gist was created here is the bl.ock.org link http://bl.ocks.org/CrandellWS/153bcfa208e2bde8a353

```js
    // Add commas to numbers. Example: 1000 becomes 1,000.
    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    function apCityNameStyling(cityStateString){
        // This isn't exact AP styling, but pretty close
        var apCities = {
            'Atlanta, Georgia': 'Atlanta',
            'Baltimore, Maryland': 'Baltimore',
            'Boston, Massachusetts': 'Boston',
            'Chicago, Illinois': 'Chicago',
            'Cincinnati, Ohio': 'Cincinnati',
            'Cleveland, Ohio': 'Cleveland',
            'Dallas, Texas': 'Dallas',
            'Denver, Colorado': 'Denver',
            'Detroit, Michigan': 'Detroit',
            'Honolulu, Hawaii': 'Honolulu',
            'Houston, Texas': 'Houston',
            'Indianapolis  (balance), Indiana': 'Indianapolis',
            'Las Vegas, Nevada': 'Las Vegas',
            'Los Angeles, California': 'Los Angeles',
            'Miami, Florida': 'Miami',
            'Milwaukee, Wisconsin': 'Milwaukee',
            'Minneapolis, Minnesota': 'Minneapolis',
            'Nashville-Davidson (balance), Tennessee': 'Nashville, Tennessee', // Not a standalone city, but the key here is how the Census calls Nashville, TN
            'New Orleans, Louisiana': 'New Orleans',
            'New York, New York': 'New York City',
            'Oklahoma City, Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
            'Philadelphia, Pennsylvania': 'Philadelphia',
            'Phoenix, Arizona': 'Phoenix',
            'Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania': 'Pittsburgh',
            'Salt Lake City, Utah': 'Salt Lake City',
            'San Antonio, Texas': 'San Antonio',
            'San Diego, California': 'San Diego',
            'San Francisco, California': 'San Francisco',
            'Seattle, Washington': 'Seattle',
            'St. Louis, Missouri': 'St. Louis',
            'Washington, District of Columbia': 'Washington, D.C.'
        };

        if(cityStateString in apCities){
            return apCities[cityStateString];
        } else {
            return cityStateString;
        }
    }



    var colorArray = [
        '#9ecae1',
        '#3182bd'
    ];
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(colorArray);

    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 105
    };
    var marginTop = margin.top;
    var marginLeft = margin.left;
    var marginBottom = margin.bottom;
    var marginRight = margin.right;
    var widthWithMargins = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
    var width = widthWithMargins*0.95 - marginLeft - marginRight;
    var height = 2000;
    var chart = d3.select('.chart')
        .attr('width',widthWithMargins);

    d3.csv('http://localhost/demo/dataset.php', function(error,csvData){
        var data = csvData.filter(function(d){
            return +d.population2014>=500000;
        });

        var maxPopulation2014 = d3.max(
                data,
                function(d){
                    return +d.population2014;
                }
            );
        var dataCount = data.length;

        var yearColumnNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key){
            return (key!=="Id" && key!=="City");
        });

        data.sort(
            function(a,b){
                return +b.population2014 - +a.population2014; // Sort by 2014 population, highest to lowest
            }
        );

        data.forEach(function(d){
            d.apCityName = apCityNameStyling(d.City);
            d.years = yearColumnNames.map(function(name){
                return {
                    name: name,
                    value: +d[name]
                };
            });
        });

        chart.attr('height',height);
            // .attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+','+marginTop+')');

        // X axis stuff
        var xDomainMin = 400000;
        var x = d3.scale.log()
            .domain([xDomainMin,maxPopulation2014])
            .range([0,width]); // Make range smaller than chart width so x axis doesn't go off the edge of chart's SVG canvas

        var xTicks = [
            // xDomainMin,
            500000,
            1000000,
            2000000,
            4000000,
            8000000
        ];
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .tickValues(xTicks)
            .tickFormat(d3.format('s'))
            .innerTickSize(-height)
            .orient('top');

        chart.append('g')
            .attr('class','x axis')
            .call(xAxis)
            .append('text')
                .text('Population')
                .style('text-anchor','end')
                .attr('class','axis-label')
                .attr('x',widthWithMargins/2)
                .attr('y',-25);

        var cityNameArray = data.map(function(d){
            return d.apCityName;
        });
        var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(cityNameArray)
            .rangeRoundBands([0,height-marginTop],0.15);
        var y1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(yearColumnNames)
            .rangeRoundBands([0,y0.rangeBand()]);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y0)
            .orient('left');

        chart.append('g')
            .attr('class','y axis')
            .call(yAxis);

        chart.selectAll('.y')
            .attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+')');

        chart.selectAll('.x')
            .attr('transform','translate('+marginLeft+','+marginTop+')');
        var city = chart.selectAll('.city')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class','city')
            .attr('transform',function(d){
                return 'translate('+marginLeft+','+(y0(d.apCityName)+(marginTop/2))+')';
            });
        city.selectAll('rect')
            .data(function(d){
                return d.years;
            })
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
                .attr('height',function(d){
                    return y1.rangeBand();
                })
                .attr('width',function(d){
                    return x(d.value);
                })
                .attr('y',function(d){
                    return y1(d.name);
                })
                .style('fill',function(d){
                    return color(d.name);
                })

        var popThreshold = 1500000; // Proxy for bar width
        city.selectAll('.city')
            .data(function(d){
                return d.years;
            })
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x',function(d){
                var population = d.value;
                var xPop = x(population);
                return population>=popThreshold ? xPop-3 : xPop+3;
            })
            .attr('y',function(d){
                return y1(d.name)+(y1.rangeBand()/1.3);
            })
            .attr('text-anchor',function(d){
                return d.value>=popThreshold ? 'end' : 'start';
            })
            .attr('fill',function(d){
                return d.value>=popThreshold ? '#eee' : '#000';
            })
            .attr('stroke',function(d){
                return d.value<popThreshold ? '#fff' : '';
            })
            .attr('stroke-width',function(d){
                return d.value<popThreshold ? 5 : '';
            })
            .attr('paint-order','stroke')
            .text(function(d){
                return numberWithCommas(d.value);
            });

        var insertLinebreaks = function (d,i) {
            // Get `y` value for `g` element containing each cluster of bars
                var gCityY = d3.selectAll('.city')[0][i]
                .getAttribute('transform')
                .split(',')[1]
                .replace(')','');
            var yTick = d3.selectAll('.y .tick')[0][i];
            var el = d3.select(this);
            var words = d.indexOf(', ') > -1 ? d.split(', ').map(function(w,i){return i===0 ? w+',' : w}) : d.split(' ');

            el.text('');
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(words[i]);
                if(i===0){
                    tspan.attr('dx',5);
                } else if (i > 0){
                    tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '15');
                }
            }

            if(words.length>1){
                var cityNameY = words.length===3 ? +gCityY+10 : +gCityY+20;
                yTick.setAttribute('transform','translate(-2.5,'+cityNameY+')');
            }
        };

        chart.selectAll('.y .tick text').each(insertLinebreaks);

        var legend = chart.selectAll('.legend')
            .data(yearColumnNames.slice())
            .enter()
            .append('g')
                .attr('class','legend')
                .attr('transform',function(d,i){
                    return 'translate('+marginLeft+','+(marginTop+(i*20))+')';
                })

        var legendX = width - width - marginLeft;
        legend.append('rect')
            .attr('x',legendX)
            .attr('y',-marginTop)
            .attr('height',18)
            .attr('width',18)
            .style('fill',color);

        legend.append('text')
            .attr('x', legendX + 55)
            .attr('y',-35)
            .style('text-anchor','end')
            .text(function(d){
                return d.replace(/\D/g,'');
            });
    });
```

```css
.axis {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .x line,
    .y .domain {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x line {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .x .domain {
        display: none;
    }

    .legend text,
    .axis text {
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: #000;
    }

    .city text {
        font: 16px sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<h3>How population changed in American cities with 500,000+ people, 2010-2014</h3>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
```

Comment: This helps, though I'm just missing the x axis labels in both FF and Chrome

Comment: @Username I updated the github pull request and fixed the dataset location back to relative